# How can I add new item in combo box after getting data from SQL?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Combo box in my code and I use this code to link database with combo box
:

```
            cmb_username.ItemsSource = database.vw_userss.ToList();
        cmb_username.DisplayMemberPath = "FullName";
        cmb_username.SelectedValuePath = "UserID";
```

and it is work.
but I wand to Add new static Item by myself and I used this:

cmb_username.Items.Add("every body");

and it is not working.

Comment: In fact I want to add static item

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Since @Adam Vincent correctly pointed out i should at least show the best answer before suggesting a bad workaround, here it is.

Your userControl should have a defined DataContext (a ViewModel) that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class UserListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

This view model should have an ObservableCollection of users, possibly view models as well, if you need to change some info inside the single items.

```
private ObservableCollection<UserViewModel> _users;
public ObservableCollection<UserViewModel> Users
{
    get => _users = _users ?? GetUsersFromDatabase(); // Gets users from the database if not already initialized
    set
    {
         _users = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

NotifyPropertyChanged() method is as follows:

```
public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

cmb_username's ItemsSource property should be binded to this collection, so inside the xaml you'll have:

```
<ListBox x:Name="cmb_username" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"/>
```

So, when you load a new user, you should do the following:

```
private void AddUser(UserViewModel user)
{
    Users.Add(user);
    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Users));
}
```

And the ListBox will magically update itself.

---

ORIGINAL POST:

In an ideal MVVM pattern, you would have a ViewModel with an ObservableCollection binded to the ComboBox's ItemsSource, and you would have to notify changes via the INotifyPropertyChanged's PropertyChanged event.

In this case, an awful (yet working) trick could be to initialize a new List once you get a new item from the database:

```
var list = database.vw_userss.ToList();
cmb_username.ItemsSource = list; 
cmb_username.DisplayMemberPath = "FullName";
cmb_username.SelectedValuePath = "UserID";

// ... //

var newUser = // ... get the new user from the database //;
list.Add(newUser);
cmd_username.ItemsSource = new List<User>(list);
```

Comment: If it's an awful trick, why would you want to provide it as an answer? Post the right answer!

Comment: @AdamVincent You're goddamn right. Done.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify combo box `Items` property. See this example:

```cs
private List<User> GetUsers()
{
    return new List<User>
    {
        new User { UserId = 1, FullName = "Test1"},
        new User { UserId = 2, FullName = "Test2"},
        new User { UserId = 3, FullName = "Test3"},
    };
}

private void BindUsers()
{
    var users = GetUsers(); // Get users from database
    // add your new item
    users.Add(new User { UserId = 4, FullName = "Test4"});

    cmb_username.ItemsSource = users;
    cmb_username.DisplayMemberPath = "FullName";
    cmb_username.SelectedValuePath = "UserID";
}
```

instead of adding to combo box items you can add new item to you list that load from database.